# Create a custom static library for microros without cross-compilation

Tags: ros2, cmake, rosbuild

I am trying to build a static custom library for Microros. I am building it directly on board (Kria KR260) and this is the cmake I am using (no cross-compilation):

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Generic)
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

# SET HERE THE PATH TO YOUR C99 AND C++ COMPILERS
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_WORKS 1 CACHE INTERNAL "")

# SET HERE YOUR BUILDING FLAGS
set(FLAGS "-O2 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions  -mcpu=cortex-a53 -nostdlib --param max-inline-insns-single=500 -DF_CPU=84000000L -D'RCUTILS_LOG_MIN_SEVERITY=RCUTILS_LOG_MIN_SEVERITY_NONE'" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS_INIT "-std=c11 ${FLAGS} -DCLOCK_MONOTONIC=0 -D'__attribute__(x)='" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT "-std=c++11 ${FLAGS} -fno-rtti -DCLOCK_MONOTONIC=0 -D'__attribute__(x)='" CACHE STRING "" FORCE)

set(__BIG_ENDIAN__ 0)
```

After starting the build using:

`ros2 run micro_ros_setup build_firmware.sh $(pwd)/my_custom_toolchain.cmake $(pwd)/my_custom_colcon.meta`

I get the following errors:

```
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:38:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
   38 |   return __builtin___sprintf_chk (__s, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   39 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__s), __fmt,
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   40 |                                   __va_arg_pack ());
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘snprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:71:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
   71 |   return __builtin___snprintf_chk (__s, __n, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   72 |                                    __glibc_objsize (__s), __fmt,
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |                                    __va_arg_pack ());
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘fprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:105:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  105 |   return __fprintf_chk (__stream, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  106 |                         __va_arg_pack ());
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘printf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:112:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  112 |   return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘dprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:149:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  149 |   return __dprintf_chk (__fd, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  150 |                         __va_arg_pack ());
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:894,
                 from /home/ubuntu/microros_ws/firmware/mcu_ws/uros/rcutils/src/allocator.c:16:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘sprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:38:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
   38 |   return __builtin___sprintf_chk (__s, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   39 |                                   __glibc_objsize (__s), __fmt,
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   40 |                                   __va_arg_pack ());
      |                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘snprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:71:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
   71 |   return __builtin___snprintf_chk (__s, __n, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   72 |                                    __glibc_objsize (__s), __fmt,
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
   73 |                                    __va_arg_pack ());
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘fprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:105:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  105 |   return __fprintf_chk (__stream, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  106 |                         __va_arg_pack ());
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘printf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:112:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  112 |   return __printf_chk (__USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt, __va_arg_pack ());
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h: In function ‘dprintf’:
/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/stdio2.h:149:10: error: invalid use of ‘__builtin_va_arg_pack ()’
  149 |   return __dprintf_chk (__fd, __USE_FORTIFY_LEVEL - 1, __fmt,
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
  150 |                         __va_arg_pack ());
      |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rcutils.dir/build.make:99: CMakeFiles/rcutils.dir/src/array_list.c.obj] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rcutils.dir/build.make:85: CMakeFiles/rcutils.dir/src/allocator.c.obj] Error 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:195: CMakeFiles/rcutils.dir/all] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
gmake: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< rcutils [12.0s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< rosidl_adapter [4.98s]
Aborted  <<< microcdr [10.5s]
```

Do you know why?

Comment: I suggest [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=invalid+use+of+%E2%80%98__builtin_va_arg_pack+%28%29%E2%80%99+aarch64-linux-gnu). On first sight the first few search results return some possible ways to resolve this error.

Comment: The problem is that I just want to compile Microros without cross-compilation because I am running the environment on the board. I cannot find ways to compile Microros without specifying a cross-compile toolchain.

Comment: In those search results, I read e.g. "Try compiling with `-fno-builtins`" or "Turning on `-fgnu89-inline` got rid of any problems I was having. Alternatively, use `-std=gnu89`". I don't know if this can also resolve your problem, and I don't know the possible impact is of these compiler flags, but in any case you do not need to cross-compile to test adding these compiler flags.